# Notification with "null" PendingIntent

Tags: android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to implement notification in Android.

Now I have a problem, I don't want to have a `PendingIntent` that user will open any `Activity`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a problem with simply setting the `contentIntent` field to `null`?

Comment: Why would you have a notification that isn't actionable for the user?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getApplicationContext(),
    0,
    new Intent(), // add this
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Interesting note, if you just pass "null" instead of pending intent, the notification is not able to be clicked.

Answer (score 7):

The following works and seems more straightforward:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);
```

Having a notification without launching a subsequent Activity seems quite sensible to me - eg "Its time to get up!.

Comment: Works on earlier version of Andorid but can conform RTE on ICS.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: When the base action of the PendingIntent is empty, it could lead to privilege leakage. Refer to CVE-2014-8609: https://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2014/Nov/81

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35700158)