# How can I put notification icon in notification area while app is running android?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I want to place my app icon in notification area while my app is running. I searched a lot and made this possible, to show it in the notification area.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setTicker("This is a new notification")
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("App runing..")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notif = builder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
    }
}
```

But what I want is I don't want to open any activity when clicking the notification.

**eg:** the battery info icon comming when battery is full, it willnot open any application or activity, also tapping it willnot remove it from notification area.

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

By changing this one line code to this

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);
```

It will work like what I want, But only on emulator, when I run this code in real device it will crash.

how to achieve this task in my app? How can I put notification icon without `Intent` and `PendingIntent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code, like mentioned in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232006/notification-with-null-pendingintent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768626/notification-without-pending-intent):

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getApplicationContext(),
    0,
    new Intent(), // add this
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not about the notification or notification manager
you can do it by changing your one line code to this,

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```